# выпадающее меню на всю ширину

Tags: html, jquery, css, меню

Добрый день.В общем,проблемка,не могу побороть и буду дико рад, если кто то подскажет. Есть навигация http://codepen.io/urbanlol/pen/vLBbZm, есть выпадающее меню, хотелось бы что бы это подменю было на 100% по ширине.

HTML

```
<header>
<div class="header-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <a href="#" id="pull"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></a>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav-header">
                        <li><a href="index.php" title="главная">главная</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="repairs.php" title="ремонт помещений">ремонт помещений</a>
                            <ul class="nav-header_dropdown">
                              <li><a href="#" title="авторский надзор">авторский надзор</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#" title="ремонт квартир">ремонт квартир</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#" title="ремонт офисов">ремонт офисов</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#" title="ремонт дома">ремонт дома</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#" title="ремонт коттеджей">ремонт коттеджей </a></li>
                            </ul>
                          <ul class="class"></ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="design.php" title="дизайн интерьера">дизайн интерьера</a>
                            <ul  class="nav-header_dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="inside_page.php" title="дизайн квартир">дизайн квартир</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="дизайн комнаты">дизайн комнаты</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="дизайн дома">дизайн дома</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" title="декоративная роспись стен">декоративная роспись стен</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="construction.php" title="строительные работы">строительные работы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.php" title="портфолио">портфолио</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contacts.php" title="контакты">контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: а вы знаете что у вас открывающий тег _header_ а закрывающий, почему-то _head_?

Comment: та не знал,эт кусочек с версточки,я просто скопировал в кодпен.исправил

Answer (score 4):

на 100% по ширене кнопки:

```
header .nav-header li:hover ul{
        //width: 126px; -- убираем это
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: left;
        background-color:rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.75);
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

На 100% родителя:

1. У родителя выпадающей меню `<li>`, надо убрать position:relative; или поставить значение static
2. у nav-header поставить `position: relative;`
3. Самой выпадающей менющке (`.nav-header_dropdown`), надо дописать

   left: 0;
   right: 0;

Тогда она будет открываться на 100% то ширине экрана.

Comment: по 100% ширине родительского размера.

Comment: а с помощью JS можно как то это преодолеть?

Comment: Можно. но уже сложнее.
Надо добавлять менюшку не в родителя (в нашем случае `<li>`) а в конец DOMа
`<!--сюда-->
</body>`
и уже там, растягивать и пизиционировать, относительно всего меню.
*Этот вариант овень не правильный, и я бы так не советовал делать. Лучше пересмотреть, что там мешает.
На крайний случай оверрайдить стили `!important`

Answer (score 0):

[Ссылка на рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/qLo1dbne/) :

```
header {
     width: 100%;
     color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.header-top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
    background: url(http://interior-design.amk-web.com/assets/images/home/header/background_menu.gif);
}
header .logo-top{
    outline: none;
    margin: 13px 0 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
header .nav-header{
position: relative;
    margin-top: 32px;
    text-align: right;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4%;

    -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear;
}
header .nav-header ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear opacity;
     }
.nav-header a {
    font-family: "BebasBold",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #EAEAEA;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}
header .nav-header li a {
    display: block;
    color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
header a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:100ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:120ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:120ms ease-in;
    transition:120ms ease-in;
}
header .nav-header a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
header .nav-header a:focus{
    outline: none;
    color: #cf383b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header .nav-header li:hover ul{
        width: 100%;
opacity: 1;
text-align: left;
background-color: rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.75);
position: absolute;
 left: 0;
top: 100%;
}
header .nav-header li:hover .class{
  position: fixed;
  background-color:rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.75);
}
header .nav-header li:hover ul li:first-child{
    margin-top: 26px;
}
header .nav-header li:hover ul li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
header .nav-header li:hover ul li{
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

header .nav-header li li a:focus::after{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но мне необходимо, что бы каждая всплывашка была под родительским li,а не в одной позиции слева)

Comment: дальше писать не вижу смысла - всё подходит - вроде - смотрите --http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZoLKx?editors=110